# Get file type using fs/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a folder with few files and I need to get type/extension of the file matching with the number I generate in my `num` variable, so is there any way I can do it?

My current code is:

```js
fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  const num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length) + 1).toString();
  // here I need to get file type/extension
}
```

`files` variable return this: `['1.jpg', '2.png', '3.gif']`

Comment: The deleted answer looks right, so what are you trying to do here? Do your files not actually have extensions?

Comment: @JasonS deleted answer just gives me ` ` (empty variable) instead of extension, and only gives me extension when I add it manually (I have to put `1.jpg` isntead of `1` which I need)

Comment: What are you calling it on?

Comment: @JasonS What do you mean by "what are you calling it on"? If you are talking about OS - it is Windows

Comment: "I have a folder with few files (e.g. 1.jpg, 2.png, 3.apng) but I need to get their type/extension" - are you calling `path.extname` on the filenames in `files` and are those the actual filenames? Or are they actually named `1`, `2`, `3`?

Comment: @JasonS `1`, `2`, `3` are actual names and I'm trying to get file extension using ```var a = path.extname(`${dir}\1`);
console.log(a)```

Comment: You should update the question to reflect that the files don't have extensions and are named `1`, `2`, `3`, ... and you want to find the type from their contents. (If that's correct).

Comment: @JasonS files do have extension and I need to get it! And I can't just type `<file_name>.<extension>` because all the files have different one

Comment: You just said they didn't. If you `console.log(files)` what *exactly* do you get?

Comment: ['1.jpg', '2.png', '3.gif']

Comment: Are you trying to *look up* a file based on matching the number you're generating?

Comment: @JasonS yes! I'm trying to get file extension based on matching the number

Comment: The question doesn't ask that, please update so the objective is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a file in a list of files regardless of the extension, use `path.basename` and `path.extname` on the files in the list to chop the extensions. For a single search, use `files.find()`.

```
const filename = files.find(x => path.basename(x, path.extname(x)) === num.toString())
```

However, for random selection purposes, it may be better to simply take a random entry from `files`. The reason is, if the files are all sequentially numbered (from 1) it's the same thing, but if they aren't all sequentially numbered (from 1) the above can break.

```
const filename = files[num] // and take away + 1 from num
```

Comment: Hello, your answer worked for me for some time but now I get `undefined` when trying to get my file (using your 2nd way to find it, also dir is not invalid, I checked it), and also I believe your 1st way has a typo in it!

Comment: What do you think is the typo? Also, are you filenames still all sequentially numbered?

Comment: I mean, using your 1st way gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'` error, and my files are: `['723.jpg', '724.jpg', '725.jpg',  '726.jpg', '727.jpg', '728.jpg',  '729.jpg', '731.jpg', '732.jpg',  '733.jpg', '734.jpg', '735.jpg',  '736.jpg', '737.jpg', '738.jpg',  '739.jpg', '740.jpg', '741.jpg',  '742.jpg', '743.jpg', '744.jpg',  '745.jpg', '746.jpg', '747.jpg',  '748.jpg', '749.jpg', '750.jpg',  '751.jpg', '752.jpg', '753.jpg',  '754.jpg', '755.png', '756.jpg', '757.jpg']`

Comment: Fixed the paren. So, your random number is 1-34 and your files go 723-757. That's why you're getting undefined and why I included #2.

Comment: yea, your 1st code is working now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching the whole file name, You can just generate a random number in ArrayList and get that file.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, files) => {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length);
  // get the random file
  let randomFileName = files[randomNum];
  console.log(randomFileName);

  /// Get unique exts
  const exts = [...new Set(files.map((name) => path.extname(name)))];
  console.log(exts);
  const randomExt = Math.floor(Math.random() * exts.length);
  
  // Get file with random ext
  randomFileName = files.find((x) => path.extname(x) === exts[randomExt]);
  console.log(randomFileName);
});
```

Comment: I don't need to generate random file with random extension, I need to get an extension of already existing file